# Is Office365 run on Microsoft or Azure?

Tags: azure, server, cloud, office365

I know that Office365 and Azure are both Microsoft products. But is Office365 provided on Azure servers? Does Microsoft have a seperate cloud provider / servers for Microsoft and Azure?

Comment: I don't think office 365 is on Azure. You can do the integration of both though.

Answer (score 1):

I have no reference documentation on this but I once listened to a Microsoft employee who explained that Office 365 is partial built on top of Azure but since Office 365 was built prior to Azure there is still some office 365 legacy that is not running on Azure. MS is however working to remove those parts if they have not already done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-moves-closer-to-running-all-of-its-own-services-on-azure/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20committed%20a%20decade%20ago,t%20actually%20hosted%20on%20Azure.&text=%22Azure%20is%20the%20cloud%20platform,cloud%20services%2C%20including%20Microsoft%20Teams) to see the updates from Microsoft

In the beginning, Office 365 was a SaaS running on Microsoft's own datacenter. Now Microsoft 365, the new name of office 365, is almost completely transitioning into Azure datacenter.